# Google play apk upload error

Tags: android, google-play

Google play keep saying You need to upload icon for your apk
But i have icon in my drawable folder and signed the apk. I have the 512x512 size icon even in the apk but still google keeps giving me this error
[image]

[image]

Below is my Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.laysapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Permission to write to external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.laysapp.MyGobalApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.SplashAtivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.SignInActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenuActivity.Watch_Story"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenuActivity.What_we_about"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenuActivity.YouShare"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenuActivity.Flavor"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenuActivity.TermsandCondition"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenuActivityp.Privacy"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.FornoMenuActivity.Language"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.AdminPage.Topic_of_the_week"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.AdminPage.Hilariouscope"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.RegisteredUser.RegisteredMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.RegisteredUser.LighterSide_Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.RegisteredUser.Laughs_Compose"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.RegisteredUser.LightStories_Compose"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.RegisteredUser.Funtography_Compose"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.ReportingPages.Report_SinglePage_Laugh"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.ReportingPages.Report_SinglePage_LightStories"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.ReportingPages.Report_SinglePage_Funtography"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.ReportingPages.Report_Main_Type"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.UserOwnPage.Ownpost_Laugh"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.UserOwnPage.Ownpost_funto"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.UserOwnPage.Ownpost_Light"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.laysapp.ContentList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
<application>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload Icon of 512*512 is compulsory to upload apk file on google play otherwise google play will not allowed to upload your application.

See below link for complete information to Upload APK file on Google Play/Android Market.

[Upload applications - Google Play](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469)

Comment: @AftabAli Google Play not allowed to upload 48*48 icon.

Comment: dipak please refer to my edited question i am still having same problem after your answer

Comment: @AftabAli Your apk file is containing application icon?

Comment: yeah it contains the application icon and i signed the application and then uploading it to the google play

Comment: @AftabAli What is the name of icon and please check the icon property is set or not in application tag of your android manifest file

Comment: my icon name is "icon" and its inside the application tag refer to my manifest file

Comment: @AftabAli Rename your app icon name icon.png to ic_launcher.png and apply change in manifest file also, may be it will solve your problem.

Comment: i already did that just now same issue.. I replaced all the default icons in the drawable folder of each size and place my 512x512 icons in it

Comment: @AftabAli If possible, After 9 pm i will solve your problem using team viewer.

Comment: 9 PM According to Pakistan time ?

Comment: Sure i l be online on Skype userID aftab_sikander i l be waiting for you after 8 PM Pakistan time

Comment: @AftabAli Ok, now accept this answer and send me request in my skype id dipak.keshariya

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21995/discussion-between-aftab-ali-and-dipak-keshariya)